# Updating/inserting data into another MS Access table automatically

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two MS access tables: local_orders and linked_orders.

When a record gets inserted, deleted, or updated in local_orders, I need the same done in linked_orders. It seems like I can just use the AfterUpdate and AfterInsert macros. Where I'm stuck is what the code would look like. I need to loop through all the columns in local_orders and set the row in linked_orders to have the exact same data.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you duplicating data? Edit question to show sample data as text tables. What are table relationships?

Comment: Either execute an UPDATE action SQL or open a recordset and edit it. This is common topic and many examples. Do research, make attempt, and when you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: The data is being duplicated into a linked table. The documentation is so spare. Any help you can provide would be great.

Comment: I don't use macros, only VBA. There are lots of examples. One approach is to execute action SQL with code behind form like: `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET field = " & Me. textboxname`. Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with posted comments: you should do an attempt and post a more specific question. Anyway, let me try to give you some hints so you can start.

You have to create a Form from your table Local_orders. You can do this using the Form Wizzard from the Create ribbon.

Open the Local_orders Form in **Design view**, and show its properties. Show the properties of the Form as such (not the ones of one of its fields or heading). Within the properties of the Form as such, locate the property "Has Module" and set it to "Yes".

Now locate the property "After Update" and click on it. On the rightmost side you will see a box with three dots. Click on it and a pop-up window will be shown. There will be three options: click on the one about Code (called "Code Generator" or something similar").

This will open the VBA editor, in a module associated to the form. The module will have the following skeleton of a VBA procedure.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

End Sub
```

You need to write in the body of that procedure the required VBA code such that taking the information of the record that has been modified from the Table Local_orders, it should modify the corresponding record in the Table Linked_orders accordingly.

You will then need to write equivalent VBA procedures for Form_BeforeConfirmDeletion(), Form_AfterConfirmDeletion( )and Form_AfterInsert() (or roughly similar names).